# SQL Server Replication across a unidirectional gateway

Tags: sql-server-2005, transactional-replication, secure-gateway

We would like to replicate a SQL Server 2005 database across a unidirectional gateway between a very secure Process LAN and a somewhat less secure Business LAN.  Does anyone know:

1. If there is a way to have SQL Server perform the replication without handshaking from the target SQL Server/DB on the Business LAN?
2. If a third party product or software library is available which will help with this desired functionality?

Both the source and the target databases would be on a Windows Server 2003 or 2008 OS.

Any alternate solutions or advise would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> If there is a way to have SQL Server perform the replication without
>   handshaking from the target SQL Server/DB on the Business LAN?

SQLServer native replication can not be used over a hardware-enforced unidirectional communications channel, sorry. Native SQLServer replication uses a variety of acknowledgement mechanisms at different levels of the network stack.

> If a third party product or software library is available which will
>   help with this desired functionality?

Waterfall and Owl both have hardware-enforced unidirectional products focused on sending information from Process LANs to Business LANs. Only Waterfall has a SQLServer replication product.

> Both the source and the target databases would be on a Windows Server
>   2003 or 2008 OS. Any alternate solutions or advise would be greatly
>   appreciated.

The Waterfall solution runs on both OS's.